# Texture seams broken

Tags: texturing

I tried importing some assets from an psx game but when it comes to the textures they got seams everywhere. I tried resizing the textures which improved the model but some seams I just can't get rid off ( it's way too unpractical anyways ). The textures are broken up into hundreds of tiny pieces because of the used engine I suppose which makes it ten times harder. Is there some setting in Blender to get rid of it? [image]

Edit: As suggested by TheLabCat i only had to change the interpolation mode to "nearest".

[image]

Comment: That actually fixed it without any work needed. Thank you so much!

Comment: you’re welcome :-) I’ve transferred it to answer so it will no longer appear in the unanswered questions list.

Answer (score 2):

Comment echo:
I think this is happening because as blender scales the images up, blackness around them leaks in at the edges because of interpolation. Thus, putting multiple images next to each other really helps show off the effect. You can try setting interpolation on everything to “nearest” which basically turns it off, which should help fight seams. However, I recommend using an external image editor like GIMP to just edit the pieces together first.